# On which site do telecommunication questions about 4G flows without authentication belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

It's to me unclear on which Stack Exchange telecommunication questions (in particular for [4G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4G) standard related topics) belong to.

The question is regarding the beginning of the [UE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_equipment) registering on [S1AP](https://www.synopsys.com/software-integrity/security-testing/fuzz-testing/defensics/protocols/s1ap-server.html)/NAS level.

Once the UEs send the MME the InitiatingMessage of type Attach Request, what are the possible scenarios in the context of the UE avoiding authenticating to the network, and vice versa (network to UE).

Would [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) be a good fit?

Comment: Directly asking for a source or biblography would probably closed. On the correct site, asking for *what* you need would be better and hopefully you get a source in the answer

Comment: Question has been narrowed down as per EDIT suggestions.

Comment: Possibly [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but they don't seem to have many 3G/4G questions